# Performing a deep copy within a copy constructor in java

Tags: java, class, copy-constructor

Suppose I was building a copy constructor within a very complex object.
What would be the quickest way to perform a deep copy?
Obviously 
this = copy.clone(); 
is bad code.
Ideally, I would be looking for something of about that length though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not short enough, but you could try doing a one-line call to the mainConstructor...

```html
public MyObject(String propertyA, String propertyB)
{
  //original contstructor code
}

public MyObject(MyObject objectToCopy)
{
  //copy the input to THIS using the normal constructor
  MyObject(objectToCopy.propertyA, objectToCopy.propertyB);
}
```